# Counting each day in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe 'df':

[image]

I would like to add an additional column named 'Day No' which adds a count to each day. Desired output below:

[image]

This wont reset at the end of each month, the count will just continue. For example at the end of the year it will read 365 for all the 1 hour entries in the last day of the year. The dtype of column 'Datetime' is datetime64[ns].

Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: did the answer worked for you?

Comment: great! consider accepting the answer that worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# convert to datetime and extract dayofyear

df['Day No']= pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], dayfirst=True).dt.dayofyear
```

**PS**: if you had shared df constructor or as text, i would have been able to share the result

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the result of enumerated `unique` values:

```
reversed_dict = dict(enumerate(df['DateTime'].unique(), 1))

df['Day No'] = df['DateTime'].map({v:k for k,v in reversed_dict.items()})
```

Comment: Nuri the above worked I supposed but the day number didn't repeat for each hour of the day as shown in the images I provided.